# Sql Server 2008 Replicate Synonym?

Tags: sql-server, replication, synonym

I plan on updating some table names by create a synonym of the old name and renaming the table to what I want it to be. Can replication properly reference a synonym?

Also as a side question, is there an easy way to see if a specific table is actually being replicated? (via a query perhaps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so.  Replication works by reading the log and there are no log records generated for a synonym.  As to your question about finding out which tables are replicated, a query on sysarticles in the table should get you where you want to go.  HTH.